# How to fetch the database values to the dropdown menu in c#.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am using mysql database with my .net application. I have a column animal_reservatory. I am trying to fetch the column values to the the drop down. I am not able to get it working.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"
                  runat="server" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string scon = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=animal_adoption_site;UID=root;";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(scon);
    String s = "select * from animal_details";
    MySqlDataAdapter dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
    while (ds.Read())
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(ds[0].ToString(), ds[0].ToString()));
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

I am getting

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataSet'

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by _not able to get it working_ exactly? Any exception or error message? Unexpected result? And you never fill your `DataSet` so you never go into your `while` statement.

Comment: @SonerGönül Updated post..

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you can't get the first element of a `DataSet` like that.

What would you expect this to return?

```
yourDataSet[0].ToString()
```

If you wanted the first `DataTable`, you might've meant to try this:

```
yourDataSet.Tables[0].ToString()
```

But calling `ToString()` on a `DataTable` doesn't make sense either.

Instead of filling the `Items` collection one record at a time, just assign the entire result set at once to the `DataSource` property. *(Also, you never actually retrieved the results, as Soner pointed out.)*

```
using (var dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con))
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    dat.Fill(dt);  // retrieve records

    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

I'm not sure, but you may need to set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` values on the `DropDownList` as well, based on the name of the column in the `DataTable`.